# How to return a number using generics in Java?

Tags: java, generics

I have a simple class like the one below, but I have a question about using generics to return a value.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Box<T extends Number> {
    private ArrayList<T> list;
    public Box(){
        list = new ArrayList<T>();
    }
    public T get(int i){
        if(i <list.size())
            return list.get(i);
        else
            return 0; // Problem
    }
}
```

I **must** get 0 (or 0.0 - it depends on the value of T) when i < list.size() is not **null**.  How can I code this properly to do that?

Comment: Return `null` instead, 0 is not an object.

Comment: The problem is that although you wrote "return 0", java needs to return an instance of class T, which is not known at compile time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you *really* want to return 0 by default, you could do something like this:

```
public abstract class Box<T extends Number> {
    private List<T> list;

     public Box(){
        list = new ArrayList<T>();
    }

    public T get(int i){
        if(i <list.size())
            return list.get(i);
        else
            return getDefault();
    }

    protected abstract T getDefault();
}
```

Then have an implementation for each Number subtype you want to support, eg

```
public class IntegerBox extends Box<Integer> {

    @Override
    protected Integer getDefault() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class DoubleBox extends Box<Double> {

    @Override
    protected Double getDefault() {
        return 0D;
    }
}
```

etc.

A nice feature of this is that it can return any default, not just zero...and the same principle would work for any type of Object, not just Numbers.

Comment: While this can be a *good* solution, you must implement a child for every class that extends `Number`: `Byte`, `Short`, `Integer`, `Long`, `Float`, `Double`, `BigInteger`, `BigDecimal`, `AtomicInteger` (and on...). There is more code doing this than just handling a `null` result or handling an `Exception`.

Comment: Yeah there's more code...but it's giving the original asker what he asked for!

Comment: IMO the effort for doing the *good* design is not worth it for this specific case.

Comment: I think this is overkill compared to just parameterizing it.  Parameterizing still allows one generic class, and puts roughly the same burden on the caller.

Comment: I guess it depends on whether you're writing a library or an application.

Answer (score 9):

If you really need your `Box` to return a zero or default value that when your get does not find a match, you can have a constructor parameter for the zero or default of type T.

Then return that default value in your `get` method.

Example:

```
public class Box<T extends Number> {
    private ArrayList<T> list;
    private T defaultValue;
    public Box( T defaultValue){
        list = new ArrayList<T>();
        this.defaultValue = defaultValue;
    }
    public T get(int i){
        if(i <list.size())
            return list.get(i);
        else
            return defaultValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`0` is an `int` and generics works only with object references (not primitive types). A way to fix your code would be returning `null` instead.

```
public T get(int i){
    if(i <list.size()) {
        return list.get(i);
    }
    return null; // Problem solved
}
```

---

> I **must** get 0 (or 0.0 - it depends on T) when i < list.size() not `null`

Take into account that the presentation themes as *show 0 to user* must be handled by the classes/methods that shows the data, not by these methods. This means, **there's no way to return 0 when you must return an object reference**.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that without creating subclasses for all the types and without parameterizing and explicitly checking the type.  And this is normal: I could create a type

```
public StrictlyPositiveInteger implements Number
```

that doesn't even have the value 0, and then do

```
Box<StrictlyPositiveInteger> box = new Box<>();
```

In other words: you want specific behaviour for specific types, so you can't do it in a generic way.

Comment: Solid explanation and example.